# SourceInsight Macro to type text in current buffer?

Tags: source-insight

Is there a macro to type text in the current buffer?  I see the macro to insert a line, I want to insert a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  The function is not named what you would expect:

```
buf = GetCurrentBuf()  
SetBufSelText(buf, "nr5g_ml1_rfmgr_pcm_")
```